# VBA decimal separator error

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with VBA decimal separator.

My file use a form to input data into tabs.

My Variables are Currency type.

Whenever a user enter 1,25 in the form and validate the correct amount goes in the file (ie the comma is used as a decimal separator) however if a user enter 1,256 then 1 256 is input in the file.  If a user enter 1.256 then the correct value 1,256 is input. 
The real problem is that if a user input 1.256 in the form, validate and then reload the form on the same excel line the form will display 1,256 as excel displays it. Thus, if the user validate again the amount 1 256 will be input.

I've tried to change excel and VBA settings to use "," as the decimal separator and nothing as the thousand separator but the problem stays.

How can I solve this **without** replacing any "," by a "." when the form is loaded from the file and tell my users to use "." ?

**EDIT :**
Here comes a part of the code (I removed a lot of other variables used in the tabs) :

```
Option Explicit


Public ReaQte As Long
Public ReaCost As Currency

Sub InitializeVariables()

    'INITIALIZE COLUMNS
    ReaQteCol = Worksheets("!V").Cells(3, 23)
    ReaCostCol = Worksheets("!V").Cells(4, 23)

    'INITIALIZE VARIABLES

    ReaQte = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ReaQteCol)
    ReaCost = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ReaCostCol)

End Sub

Sub LoadCurrentRecordDetails()
    'LOAD ROW IN FORM

    'LOAD FORM

    Menu.ReaQte.Text = ReaQte
    Menu.ReaCost.Text = ReaCost

    'SET VISIBILITY OF FORM ITEMS

    'DISPLAY FORM
    Menu.Show
End Sub

Sub ModifyRecord(TargetRow As Long)
    'INSERT FORM VALUES INTO LINE


    If EstPoche Then
        ActiveSheet.Cells(TargetRow, BudCol) = Menu.BudPoche.Text
        ActiveSheet.Cells(TargetRow, MonthBudCol) = Menu.MonthBudList.Text
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Cells(TargetRow, ReaQteCol) = Menu.ReaQte.Text
        ActiveSheet.Cells(TargetRow, ReaCostCol) = Menu.ReaCost.Text

    End If

    Unload Menu
End Sub
```

Basically this works as follow :

The file has a lot of different sheets used by different people. All sheets have the same tab formats. Whenever a user click on a cell into a tab it opens a form and load the row details into the tab. The user can then modify stuff in the form and validate to input that into the tab.

**EDIT 2 : Partial Solution**

I realized that despite the fact that my variables are Currency type, the value stored in the form isn't of any type. Thus converting it like this :

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(TargetRow, ReaCostCol) = CCur(Menu.ReaCost.Value)
```

Solve the problem. However I only get 2 digits after coma using this method.

Comment: `CCur` (or any built-in conversion function for that matter) will **not** produce correct results given non-matching decimal separators. For example on a machine with en-US number formats, `CCur("1,45")` returns `145`, not `1.45`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> If EstPoche Then
>     ActiveSheet.Cells(TargetRow, BudCol) = Menu.BudPoche.Text
>     ActiveSheet.Cells(TargetRow, MonthBudCol) = Menu.MonthBudList.Text
> Else
>     ActiveSheet.Cells(TargetRow, ReaQteCol) = Menu.ReaQte.Text
>     ActiveSheet.Cells(TargetRow, ReaCostCol) = Menu.ReaCost.Text
> End If
> ```

You're assigning cell values to `String` values. Convert them to `Double` before.

```
If EstPoche Then
    ActiveSheet.Cells(TargetRow, BudCol) = CDbl(Menu.BudPoche.Text)
    ActiveSheet.Cells(TargetRow, MonthBudCol) = CDbl(Menu.MonthBudList.Text)
Else
    ActiveSheet.Cells(TargetRow, ReaQteCol) = CDbl(Menu.ReaQte.Text)
    ActiveSheet.Cells(TargetRow, ReaCostCol) = CDbl(Menu.ReaCost.Text)
End If
```

This conversion will fail if VBA doesn't understand what's in the textboxes as numeric values; in that case you'll want further text-processing logic to make the string representation of the values line up with the number format VBA is expecting to see.

One way to achieve this is to handle the textboxes' `KeyDown` events, and outright *forbid* the entry of illegal characters (e.g. spaces, commas).

Another way to achieve this is to implement your own string-to-double conversion function, and implement it in such a way that you parse the input's decimal and thousands separators and replace them with the system-defined separators, which you can get from the `Application.International` property:

```
Dim decimalSeparator As String
decimalSeparator = Application.International(XlApplicationInternational.xlDecimalSeparator)
Dim thousandsSeparator As String
thousandsSeparator = Application.International(XlApplicationInternational.xlThousandsSeparator)
```

Have fun implementing it! Or.. I'm 99% sure there's already an implementation of it somewhere on this site.

Just to be clear:

> *How can I solve this **without replacing any "," by a "."** when the form is loaded from the file and tell my users to use "." ?*

You can't.

Comment: This is close to my second edit. I already have a check that verify that the input is correct (numeric in this case). However I don't understand why converting value with 'CCur' only keep 2 digits after coma while your method with 'CDbl' keep all the digits. Currency variable have 4 digits after coma right ? And actually this solve my problem so YES I CAN ;)

Comment: @Lich4r I think you're mistaking the cell representation of the values (which are formatted per the cell's `NumberFormat`, apparently with 2 decimals), and the actual return value of the conversion function, which you can visualize by piping its output to the *immediate pane*, e.g. with `Debug.Print` instructions. `Debug.Print CCur(1.2345)` prints `1.2345` in the immediate pane, not `1.23`.

Comment: FWIW I'd go with the `KeyDown` validation: if your users can't type a space or a comma in the field, then your code doesn't have to deal with spaces and commas.

Comment: I'm not mistaking. Using CDbl the form shows all the decimals while using CCur the form onyl shows 2 decimals. I'm not speaking about the displayed value in excel cells but the real value displayed in the form when I load it again.

Comment: Then you have other code fiddling with the values somewhere. `?CCur("1.2345")` in the immediate pane prints `1.2345` with all the decimals.

Comment: I've checked but I have none. Using `CCur` 1,23 is input in excel (value of the cell when looking at the formula bar in excel). Using `CDbl` 1,2345 is input in excel.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161053/discussion-between-mats-mug-and-lich4r).

Comment: From linked chat: writing `Currency` values into `Range.Value` removes decimals. Writing them into `Range.Value2` fixes it.